# How to get external api data using inline editor in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, fulfillment

I've got a Dialogflow agent for which I'm using the Inline Editor (powered by Cloud Functions for Firebase). When I try to get external api data by using `request-promise-native` I keep getting `Ignoring exception from a finished function` in my firebase console.

```
function video(agent) {
    agent.add(`You are now being handled by the productivity intent`);
    const url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";
    return request.get(url)
        .then(jsonBody => {
            var body = JSON.parse(jsonBody);
            agent.add(body.data[0].first_name)
            return Promise.resolve(agent);
        });
}
```

Comment: to access the external api's you need to have a paid account, your code looks ok.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code looks correct. The exception in this case might be that you're not using a paid account, so network access outside Google is blocked. You can probably see the exact exception by adding a catch block:

```
function video(agent) {
    agent.add(`You are now being handled by the productivity intent`);
    const url = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";
    return request.get(url)
        .then(jsonBody => {
            var body = JSON.parse(jsonBody);
            agent.add(body.data[0].first_name)
            return Promise.resolve(agent);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Problem making network call', err);
            agent.add('Unable to get result');
            return Promise.resolve(agent);
        });
}
```

(If you do this, you may want to update your question with the exact error from the logs.)

Comment: well thank you prisoner, now I might go on my billing part... then i'll let you know about firebase function's log... and one more thing I would like ask that can I use my sql database for my agent responses? I mean is that suitable to use of sql in inline editor or should I go for webhook.

Comment: Normally I would say to ask that as a new StackOverflow question so others can benefit from the question and answer. But this one is simple - the Inline Editor **is** a webhook. Just a simple one that you can edit inside Dialogflow itself. (If you do have followup questions on this - post a new question, please.)

Comment: @Prisoner When I use this code, I'm getting this error in Firebase logs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at video (/user_code/index.js:48:9)
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:303:44). What could be the problem?

Comment: @Ambigus9 - Difficult to tell, but there are some possibilities. I suggest you post a new StackOverflow question showing the code you're using, the error you're getting, the environment you're working in, and any other information that may help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Inline Editor uses Firebase. If you do not have a paid account with Firebase, you will not be able to access external APIs.

Comment: yes I understand and you're right but i mean that... is my code perfect? I mean, Does external api can be call by this way?

Comment: you may use axios as request does not have its own Promise. https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: They indicated they are using `request-promise-native`, which does return a Promise. That part appears correct.

Comment: I had a some issues with that module and had to use regular request module inside a promise. So I shared axios.